# How can I store form input values as object of an array in another file in react using hooks?

Tags: arrays, reactjs, react-hooks, react-hook-form

I'm trying to store input of the user which is being entered in a form that's located in FooterComponent.js and store that input in an array which is located in contact.js
im trying to achieve so by using hooks in react.

here is my footerComponent.js that contains the form:

```js
const FooterComponent = () => {

const [inputVal, setInputValue] = useState({
    xemail: "",
    message: "",
  });

  function handleChange(event) {
    console.log(event);
    const { name, value } = event.target;
    console.log(`Name: ${name} and value: ${value}`);
    setInputValue({ ...inputVal, [name]: value });
  }

  const handleSubmit = (event) => {
    alert(`Email: ${inputVal.xemail} & Message: ${inputVal.message}`);
    event.preventDefault();   
  };

return (
    <React.Fragment>
    <form className="form-center" onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
                <div className="footer-form-group">
                  <label htmlFor="exampleInputEmail1">Email*</label>
                  <input
                    type="email"
                    className="form-control"
                    id="exampleInputEmail1"
                    name="xemail"
                    defaultValue={inputVal.email}
                    onChange={handleChange}
                    required
                  />
                </div>
                <div className="footer-form-group">
                  <label htmlFor="exampleInputMessage">Message*</label>
                  <br />
                  <textarea
                    id="exampleInputMessage"
                    cols="10"
                    rows="5"
                    name="message"
                    defaultValue={inputVal.message}
                    onChange={handleChange}
                    required
                  />
                </div>
                <div className="footer-form-group">
                  <button type="submit" className="btn submit-btn">
                    SEND
                  </button>
                </div>
              </form>
</React.Fragment>
  );
};
```

i want to  store the new inputs of the form in contact.js in the array of form:

```js
    const contact[
    {
      email: "abc@gmail.com",
      message: "Hello world 1",
    },
    {
      email: "xyz@gmail.com",
      message: "Hello world 2",
    }
  ]
```

Comment: Do you want to give your contact component access to use footercomponent input values?
this is what I undertstand

Comment: Thinking in "files" is a common misconception. In the end your whole application will often be just a single file. You should better think in scopes. If you need to share data between adjacent components this usually means that you need to keep that data in a component that is a parent of both. This is often referred to as lifting-state-up. You can then either pass it down as props or use react context to access that state.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Context API to access data outside of the component.
https://codesandbox.io/s/pensive-merkle-otwtl?file=/src/App.js

However, to write the data file to disk you need something that will give you access to the file system (eg NodeJS).
Here is more about working with files in Node: https://nodejs.dev/learn/writing-files-with-nodejs

Alternatively, you can save this data in the browser's memory using localStorege: https://developer.mozilla.org/pl/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage

However, saving files to disk using React alone is unfortunately impossible.